# Error when building models from propel schema

Tags: php, macos, orm, mamp, propel

I got the errors below when running the command below. I already have my schema file generated from reverse engineering through propel.

**Command**

```
vendor/bin/propel build
```

**Error 1**

```
[RuntimeException]                
Unable to write the "" directory
```

**Error 2**

```
[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]  
Failed to create "": mkdir(): Invalid path.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like propel doesn't know where to put the files. Typing `propel --help` will give you command line options. There you find an option to specify an output folder.

```
propel model:build --output-dir C:\temp
```

(you'll have to specify a local OS X path instead of my Windows temp folder)

As I'm just trying out propel myself, the following post has lead me to the suspicion my propel.ext file is incomplete.

https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/694